# Using invoke command to create com object on a remote system

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, windows-update

This command is used to get the status of Microsoft update. In my environment it is set to never check for updates.

```
$WUSettings = (New-Object -Com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Settings
```

But I want to run this command on remote computer. I am using `Invoke-Command` but its giving null value. If I go in the  system itself, the command will work, but its not working remotely.

Comment: Get-WUSettings.ps1 script on [PowerShell gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/1.6.0.2/Content/Get-WUSettings.ps1) supports -Computername param

Comment: Or use PowerShell remoting? https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Comment: @Remko What do you think `Invoke-Command` does?

Answer (score 2):

Tested this and have the same issue. Seems it's [not supported](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/new-object-com-microsoft-update-autoupdate-doesnt-return-object-ps-remoting/).

There's a [script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/c5cc2865-3539-4929-b929-ddb17ca206be/problem-retrieving-correct-windows-update-settings-from-remote-computers-using-powershell-script?forum=ITCG) that you can use that does something similar, but uses another call instead of a `COM` object.